# Matrix Template Class passing parameter by const reference

Tags: c++, templates, class-template

Trying to write a template class for a matrix object.
Getting compiling errors:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(606): error C2558: class 'Matrix' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'
>   1>          with 1>          [ 1>              T=float 1>          ]
>   1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(605) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)' 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>              _Ty=Matrix 1>          ] 1> 
>   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\xmemory0(751) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)'
>   being compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Ty=Matrix 1>          ] 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits(743) : see
>   reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being
>   compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Ty=Matrix 1>          ] 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector(655) : see
>   reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Ty>' being
>   compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Ty=std::allocator> 1>          ] 1>          e:\projects\work\nns\fifteenstepstut\fifteensteps\fifteensteps\source.cpp(35)
>   : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>'
>   being compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Ty=Matrix 1>          ] 1> 1>Build FAILED. 1>

AND

> ClCompile: 1>  Source.cpp
>   1>e:\projects\work\nns\fifteenstepstut\fifteensteps\fifteensteps\matrix.h(80):
>   error C2664: 'Matrix::Matrix(Matrix &)' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'Matrix (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'Matrix &' 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>              T=float 1>          ] 1>
>   e:\projects\work\nns\fifteenstepstut\fifteensteps\fifteensteps\matrix.h(74)
>   : while compiling class template member function 'Matrix
>   Matrix::dot(const Matrix &)' 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   T=float 1>          ] 1>
>   e:\projects\work\nns\fifteenstepstut\fifteensteps\fifteensteps\source.cpp(62)
>   : see reference to function template instantiation 'Matrix
>   Matrix::dot(const Matrix &)' being compiled 1>          with 1> 
>   [ 1>              T=float 1>          ] 1>
>   e:\projects\work\nns\fifteenstepstut\fifteensteps\fifteensteps\source.cpp(38)
>   : see reference to class template instantiation 'Matrix' being
>   compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>              T=float 1>
>   ]
>   1>e:\projects\work\nns\fifteenstepstut\fifteensteps\fifteensteps\matrix.h(84):
>   error C2664: 'Matrix::Matrix(Matrix &)' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'Matrix (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'Matrix &' 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>              T=float 1>          ] 1> 1>Build
>   FAILED.

"Matrix.h"

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Matrix {
private: 
    std::vector<T> data;
    int rows;
    int cols;

public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(std::vector<T>, int rows, int cols);
    Matrix(Matrix<T>&); //change with this one
    //Matrix(const Matrix<T>&); //Will need to uncomment to test the 3rd error
    void print();
    Matrix<T> transpose();
    Matrix<T> dot(const Matrix<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> &); //error 2
    //Matrix<T&> dot(const Matrix<T> &); //dumb idea?
    //Matrix<T> dot(const Matrix<T> &); //error 1
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix() {
    data.clear();
    rows = 0;
    cols = 0;
}

template <typename T> 
Matrix<T>::Matrix(std::vector<T> elements, int numRows, int numCols) {
    rows = numRows;
    cols = numCols;

    data.clear();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        data.push_back(elements[i]);
    }
}

template <typename T> 
Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix<T>& matrix) {
    rows = matrix.rows;
    cols = matrix.cols;

    data.clear();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < matrix.data.size(); i++) {
        data.push_back(matrix.data[i]);
    }
}
/* To get compiler error, exchange with a above
template <typename T> 
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& matrix) {
    rows = matrix.rows;
    cols = matrix.cols;

    data.clear();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < matrix.data.size(); i++) {
        data.push_back(matrix.data[i]);
    }
}*/

template <typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::dot(const Matrix<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> & rhs) { //ERROR 2
//Matrix<&T> dot(const Matrix<T> &) {   
//Matrix<T> dot(const Matrix<T> &) { ERROR 1
    if(cols != rhs.rows) {
        std::cout << "Error! Can not resolve dot product on these matrices!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Requested: [" << rows << "x" << cols << "] <alt+7> [" << rhs.rows << "x" << rhs.cols << "]" << std::endl;
        Matrix<T> matrix();
        return matrix;
    }

    Matrix<T> matrix();
    return matrix;
}

template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::print() {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << data[i] << ", ";
        if((i+1) % cols == 0)
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::transpose() {
    std::vector<T> vec;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        vec.push_back(data[(cols*(i%rows)+i/rows)]);
    }
    return Matrix<T>(vec, cols, rows);
}
```

I've read several different ideas on how to correct this, but not really sure what the issue is.  A lot of places talk about passing just T as a const reference, but in this case, I'm passing the class as a const reference.  Does not seem to like that.

I finally decided to see what happens if a implement a const reference copy constructor.

I then get this error:

> unresolved external symbol "public: class Matrix __thiscall
>   Matrix::dot(class Matrix const &)"
>   (?dot@?$Matrix@M@@QAE?AV1@ABV1@@Z) referenced in function "void
>   __cdecl testMatrixClass(void)" (?testMatrixClass@@YAXXZ)

How could I accomplish passing this class as a const reference if at all possible?

Thanks!

Test implementation

SOURCE.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


////TODO: Find alternatives to these...
//typedef std::vector<std::vector<float>> Matrix;
//typedef std::vector<float> Vector;
//using LMath::operator+;
//using LMath::operator==;



//void testMatrix(); //testing function.
//Matrix loadData(std::string); //Not implemented yet
//bool saveData(Matrix, std::string); //Not implemented yet


void testMatrixClass();

int main() {

    //testMatrix();
    testMatrixClass();

    return 0;
}


void testMatrixClass() {

    std::vector<Matrix<float>> testResults;
    std::vector<std::string> testInfo;

    Matrix<float> temp;
    testResults.push_back(temp);
    testInfo.push_back("Default Constructor");

    std::vector<float> tempVec;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        tempVec.push_back((float)(i%3));
    }

    Matrix<float> temp2(tempVec, 3, 3);
    testResults.push_back(temp2);
    testInfo.push_back("Vector constructor");

    testResults.push_back(temp2.transpose());
    testInfo.push_back("Vector transpose");

    tempVec.push_back(10.0);
    Matrix<float> temp3(tempVec, 5, 2);
    testResults.push_back(temp3);
    testInfo.push_back("Vector constructor");

    testResults.push_back(temp3.transpose());
    testInfo.push_back("Vector transpose");

    testResults.push_back(temp2.dot(temp2));
    testInfo.push_back("Dot product");

    testResults.push_back(temp2.dot(temp3));
    testInfo.push_back("Error Dot Product");

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < testResults.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Test: " << testInfo[i] << ": " << std::endl;;
        testResults[i].print();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
private: 
    std::vector<T> data;
    int rows;
    int cols;

public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(std::vector<T>, int rows, int cols);
    //Matrix(Matrix<T>&);
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>&);
    void print();
    Matrix<T> transpose();
    Matrix<T> dot(const Matrix<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> &);
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix() {
    data.clear();
    rows = 0;
    cols = 0;
}

template <typename T> 
Matrix<T>::Matrix(std::vector<T> elements, int numRows, int numCols) {
    rows = numRows;
    cols = numCols;

    data.clear();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        data.push_back(elements[i]);
    }
}

template <typename T> 
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& matrix) {
    rows = matrix.rows;
    cols = matrix.cols;

    data.clear();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < matrix.data.size(); i++) {
        data.push_back(matrix.data[i]);
    }
}


template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::print() {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << data[i] << ", ";
        if((i+1) % cols == 0)
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::transpose() {
    std::vector<T> vec;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        vec.push_back(data[(cols*(i%rows)+i/rows)]);
    }
    return Matrix<T>(vec, cols, rows);
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::dot(const Matrix<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> & rhs) {
    if(cols != rhs.rows) {
        std::cout << "Error! Can not resolve dot product on these matrices!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Requested: [" << rows << "x" << cols << "] <alt+7> [" << rhs.rows << "x" << rhs.cols << "]" << std::endl;
        Matrix<T> matrix;
        return matrix;
    }

    Matrix<T> matrix;
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: The shown code fails to meet the requirements of a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], and, as such, is likely to be completely unanswerable.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How about that homie?

Comment: I have no compiler accessible right now, but what sticks out is that you return `Matrix<T>` in several places; that requires a copy method. Try returning a `const Matrix<T>`

Comment: @Aganju Well I have implemented the copy constructor, however I tried this suggestion.  No result was different for a few of the different ideas I've been trying.

Comment: Not worth putting this as an answer as it has been covered already below, but here is some commented code. https://ideone.com/nziYqb - You should also add a move constructor.

Comment: I'm not seeing a need for a copy constructor at all. The only complex `Matrix` member is a `std::vector`, and `std::vector` is Rule of Five complaint. `Matrix` should be able to observe the [Rule of Zero.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Totally spot on.  Commenting out the copy constructor also worked fine.  I guess my main error came from the fact I was defining a function and not creating an instance of the class, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @Chemistpp you've understood correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with the shown code.

1) The copy constructor is wrong:

```
Matrix(Matrix<T>&);
```

Copy constructors must take a `const` reference as a parameter:

```
Matrix(const Matrix<T>&);
```

The actual declaration, in the header file, needs to be changed as well.

2) The second problem is [The Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse):

```
Matrix<T> matrix();
return matrix;
```

This should simply be changed to:

```
Matrix<T> matrix;
return matrix;
```

Or simply to:

```
return Matrix<T>();
```

This occurs in two places in the shown code.

Once the above two problems are fixed, the shown code compiles for me, with gcc 8.

Comment: Nailed it homie!