# Default constructor is not being called?

Tags: c++, constructor, default

Lets say I have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = { std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl; }
}
```

In the main function I call the following:

```
int main()
{
    Foo bar1(); // This doesn't echo "Hello World!"
    Foo bar2 = Foo(); // This does echo "Hello World!"
}
```

I don't understand why this would be occurring?

Comment: `Foo bar1();` declares a function

Comment: Ah yeah, this is called "most vexing  parse", I believe.

Comment: Use `Foo bar1;` with no brackets or `Foo bar1{};` with curly brackets

Comment: Thank you @zzxyz Makes perfect sense looking into the principle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse

Comment: For future reference, this really isn't a MVP (but is probably the most inaccurately cited example of one, people just assume it is). The V in MVP likewise involves a function decl, but is considerably more counter-intuitive: `Type id( Type2() );` The linked question from BartoszKP cites the specific standard location where this is called out. It's considerably more brain food than the simple no-arg function decl you have here, so much so the standard specifically calls it out.

Comment: Thanks, @WhozCraig - Although after reading, I consider the most vexing parse less vexing than this one :)