# typename c++ and order of compiling

Tags: c++, typename

In this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typename, related to use of the keyword Typename, it is written:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t)
{
   // declares a pointer to an object of type T::bar
   T::bar * p;
}

struct StructWithBarAsType {
  typedef int bar;
};

int main() {
   StructWithBarAsType x;
   foo(x);
}
```

> The fact that in StructWithBarAsType the dependent bar is in fact a
>   type does not help since foo() could be compiled long before
>   StructWithBarAsType is seen.

I don't understand why foo() could be compiled long before StructWithBarAsType, in which case it could be so?

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  When links die or their content changes the question becomes meaningless for future readers.

Comment: ^ super vague comment. What you should do is post the code they mention so if the link ever dies or is changed your question makes sense. That's all :)

Comment: I think maybe my question is different, in substance I ask why the compiler could not see in StructWithBarAsType defintion and solve the ambiguity. Wiki says because foo() could be compiled long before StructWithBarAsType and I ask why this occours.

Comment: You ask *why* compilers don't do it this way, and I think this paragraph from the other question gives you an answer: _This will work and actually is allowed by the Standard as a possible implementation approach. These compilers [...] when an instantiation is needed, they parse the template and possibly detect errors in the definition. But instead of bothering the template's users (poor colleagues!) with errors made by a template's author, other implementations choose to check templates early on and give errors in the definition as soon as possible, before an instantiation even takes place._

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I'm giving my vote for your question being a duplicate of the other one then.

Comment: The complier could do it in this way: do not compile template, when f(x) has called see the type of x which is StructWithBarAsType so compile the template using the StructWithBarAsType information and then resolve ambiguity without typename. Maybe for technical reasons the template cannot be always parsed after f(x) called.

Answer (score 1):

When a compiler parses a C++ file, it usually builds a symbol table of identifier to types. This is important when invoking templates, as the C++ compiler will essentially do a "substitution check" to make sure that "things all work out."

The problem is this ambiguous statement:

```cpp
T::bar * p;
```

This can be interpreted as either:

1. static member variable on type `T` named `bar` multiplied by `p`: `? operator*(? T::bar, ? p)`
2. declaration of a pointer of type `T::bar*` with name `p`.

This creates some sort of ambiguity when *parsing*, and this results in a compiler error:

```sh
g++ main.cpp && ./a.out

main.cpp: In function 'void foo(const T&)':
main.cpp:9:13: error: 'p' was not declared in this scope
    9 |    T::bar * p;
      |             ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void foo(const T&) [with T = StructWithBarAsType]':
main.cpp:14:9:   required from here
main.cpp:9:11: error: dependent-name 'T::bar' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
    9 |    T::bar * p;
main.cpp:9:11: note: say 'typename T::bar' if a type is meant
```

**`main.cpp:9:11: error: dependent-name 'T::bar' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type`**

In order to clear up this parsing error, C++ has a "syntax modification" to "signal" that an identifier in a template is intended to be a type name and not a variable name. This "syntax modification comes in the form of `typename`:

```cpp
struct StructWithBarAsType {
  typedef int bar;
};

template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t)
{
   // declares a pointer to an object of type T::bar
   typename T::bar * p;
}

int main() {
   StructWithBarAsType x;
   foo(x);
}
```

and this compiles.

Note that similar problems happen related to parsing in C++. See [the most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse).

Comment: Ok, but when the compile sees "foo(x)" with x of type StructWithBarAsType could not see in StructWithBarAsType defintion and solve the ambiguity?

Comment: Wiki says because foo() could be compiled long before StructWithBarAsType and I ask why this occours. It is impossible create a compiler to solve that kind of ambiguity?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I'd imagine the emphasis to be on "parse-time guarantees." By adding `typename`, you equip the template with the `T::Bar is-a type` association that is necessary to help the compiler verify and connect the dots with `StructWithBarAsType::bar, T = StructWithBarAsType in foo<StructWithBarAsType>(x)`.

Comment: The complier could do it in this way: do not compile template, when f(x) has called see the type of x which is StructWithBarAsType so compile the template using the StructWithBarAsType information and then resolve ambiguity without typename. Maybe for technical reasons the template cannot be always parsed after f(x) called.