# No constructor called?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy-elision

I'm trying to understand constructors calling with **l/r** values, so I created the `class A` below :

```
class A {
    public :
    A()            { cout << "called default constructor" << endl ; }
    A(const A&)    { cout << "called copy constructor" << endl ; }
    A(const A&&)   { cout << "called move constructor" << endl ; }
};
```

in the main function, I created an instance `a`

```
int main()
{
    A a(A());
    return 0;
}
```

but no constructor among the implemented constructors is called !

any explanation? thank you!

Comment: Use `{}` when calling constructors, `A a(A())` is interpreted as a function declaration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the Most Vexing Parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse) Clang warns about it as "parentheses were disambiguated as a function       declaration [-Wvexing-parse]"

Comment: Try using `a` as an object, and you'll get surprised.

Comment: This is why you should use `A a{A{}};`

Answer (score 5):

This

```
A a(A());
```

is a function declaration that has the return type `A` and one parameter of the type `A()`, which is a function type that takes no arguments and returns an `A`. The compiler implicitly adjusts the parameter to pointer type to function like `A (*)()`.

To declare an object you should write either

```
A a( ( A() ));
```

Or

```
A a {A()};
```

or for example

```
A a( A{} );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public :
    A()            { cout << "called default constructor" << endl ; }
    A(const A&)    { cout << "called copy constructor" << endl ; }
    A(const A&&)   { cout << "called move constructor" << endl ; }
};

int main() 
{
    A a1( ( A() ) );
    A a2( A{} );

    A a3 { A() };


    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
called default constructor
called default constructor
called default constructor
```

Pay attention to that in these object declarations there is copy elision.

To call for example the copy constructor you could write

```
A a1;
A a2( a1 );
```

And a simple way to invoke the move constructor is for example

```
A a1;
A a2( std::move( a1 ) );
```

Comment: @rafix07 You are right.:)