# How to get area of rectangle using class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

I have been tasked to calculate the area and perimeter of a rectangle using class. The input function is supposed to be inside class. I wrote code so far but there seem to be errors I can't detect.

Some help would be appreciated.

rectangle.h

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H
class Rectangle{
    public:
        int width, length;
        Rectangle();
        Rectangle(int width1,int length1);
        void getRectangle();
        int getArea();
        int getPerimeter();
};

#endif // RECTANGLE_H
```

rectangle.cpp

```
// oporer ta class

#include<iostream>
#include "rectangle.h"
Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
    width=0;
    length=0;
}
Rectangle::Rectangle(int width1,int length1)
{
    width=width1;
    length=length1;
}
void Rectangle::getRectangle()
{
    cin>>width>>length;
}
int Rectangle::getArea()
{
    return (width*length);
}
int Rectangle::getPerimeter()
{
    return (width+length)*2
}
// oporer ta rectangle cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rectangle.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Rectangle paraFirst();
    paraFirst.getRectangle();
    return 0;
}
// main fucntion
```

Comment: it's a bit lengthy, so i thought it would be better to post on another website, but im trying to add the code here now

Comment: You can't just copy-paste code from multiple files into an online IDE, the `#include`s wont work and obscure the actual error. But note that `Rectangle paraFirst();` will be parsed as function declaration, not as constructor call.

Comment: Have you seen the code now?

Comment: Your question would be better if you added the text of the errors. If this is Visual Studio the Output Tab is a better choice to copy the text of the error messages from than the Errors List. The reason is the output tab is more verbose and its 100% text not a separated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `#include`s work in your local setup, I see two typos here:

- `cin>>width>>length;` must `std::cin >> width >> length;`
- missing semicolon after `return (width+length)*2`

And probably the main problem:

```
Rectangle paraFirst();
```

is parsed as a declaration for a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Rectangle`. See also [Most vexing parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse). To call the default constructor simply use

```
Rectangle paraFirst;
```

or

```
Rectangle paraFirst{};
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! It helped :D