# Why not call the copy constructor?

Tags: c++

```
class MyClass{
public:
   MyClass();
   MyClass(const MyClass& my);
   MyClass(MyClass&& my);
};

void func(MyClass my);

int main()
{
   func(MyClass());
   MyClass myClass(MyClass());


   return 0;
}
```

`func(MyClass())` runs fine. And here, `MyClass()` is an anonymous instance. But `MyClass myClass(MyClass())` is a function, not an object. And here, `MyClass()` is a pointer to function. I think it should call the copy constructor but it doesn't. why?

*note : I know `myClass` is a function if it has empty parentheses.

Comment: `MyClass myClass(MyClass())` is a function *declaration*, like `int foo(int);`. By itself it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Lookup the [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: As an alternative solution, you can prefer syntax like: `MyClass myClass{MyClass()}` if you have C++11 or later, and `MyClass` does not have an initializer list constructor, or you can just use `MyClass myClass((MyClass()))` to force it thinking `MyClass()` as an object. Also [here for some reasoning about why "Most vexing parse" was introduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse) .