# c++ std::ifstream constructor: why constructor resolve with single parameter and why it cant instantiate object with c++ style

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ifstream

I want to keep a file as member of following class:

```
class MyClass
    {
    public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();

    private:
        // why this line is OK   
        std::ifstream fileOK = ifstream("..\\abc.txt");
        // why this line is NOT OK  
        std::ifstream fileNotOK("..\\abc.txt");

    };
```

However if i write that same error line inside any member function then it works:

```
MyClass::MyClass()  {
        std::ifstream fileNotOK("..\\abc.txt");
    }
```

also, I notice that, there is No constructor of [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/) that has only one parameter like: `ifstream (const char* filename)`

So How single parameter constructor works and why it cant instantiate member file object like c++ from class declaration.

Comment: `std::ifstream fileNotOK("..\\abc.txt");` [as member declaration] is parsed as function declaration, because of [most vecxing parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse). You can use `std::ifstream fileNotOK{"..\\abc.txt"};` instead.

Comment: @churill however this creates local variable that shadows class wide one with the same name. The constructors initializer list might be what he wants.

Comment: @KIIV I was talking about the one in the first snippet, have clarified it :)

Comment: Your second question: there is `explicit ifstream (const char* filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in);` - second parameter has a default value, so `ifstream("xxx");` is a valid CTor call