# Compiler does not recognize member initializer for std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cmake

I want to initialize a std::vector to have a specific length.
in the .hpp file I use

```
#include <vector>

class foo
{
foo(){};
~foo(){};
std::vector<double> pressure (4,0); //vector 4 elements = 0

void readPressure()
{
    pressure.at(0) = 1;
    pressure.at(1) = 2;
    pressure.at(2) = 3;
    pressure.at(3) = 4;
}
...
};
```

But I get the error:

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
std::vector<double> pressure(4,0);
                             ^
error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

I read that this might be due to not using C++11 but I specify in my makefile

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
```

I am compiling on a raspberry 4, g++ version is 8.3

***edited the .hpp file

Comment: why are you putting this in a .hpp file ? this should go within some .cpp file. also try following declaration: auto pressure = std::vector<double>(4, 0); to avoid most vexing parsing.

Comment: Try running cmake --build build in verbose mode to be absolutely sure about your flags (`VERBOSE=1 cmake --build build`), because this codes compiles on me [reproductible](https://godbolt.org/z/P3PYY1). Also this is not an initializer list this puts 4 zeros to the vector , not the values 4 and then zero

Comment: I suspect that it's actually a member of a class and you assumed that this detail was irrelevant. Please read about the [mcve].

Comment: What you posted [compiles](https://ideone.com/77oEFJ). Thus it is either not the problem, or what you posted isn't what you're actually doing. Posting a proper [mcve] that actually *reproduces* the problem *for us* using *only* what you posted is critical if you want us to help solve it. Unrelated, *"in the .hpp file I use..."* global decls don't belong in header files, at least not like that. So this strongly supports @molbdnilo crystal ball that this is buried in some class/template declaration that you completely neglected to mention..

Comment: yes this is inside a class. I didn't realize that was important.

as I mentioned it does not compile for me and I have no idea why and not enough knowledge about c++ to pinpoint the error more or narrow it down, that's why I posted it here

Comment: I retracted my comment, becuase your code seemed to work. Now that we can see the real code I'd like to add it again, because the problem is indeed  [Most vexing parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse). I'm pretty sure there is duplicate for this, but TL;DR; you need to initialize it in the constructor, the best would be to do it in the member initializer list .

Comment: `std::vector<double> pressure(4, 0)` -> `std::vector<double> pressure { 0, 0, 0, 0 }`

Comment: Your CMake snippet doesn't show if you before or after declaring the target.  You should follow the advice and make sure that the correct compiler flags are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) only supports brace and equal-sign initializer. E.g.

```
class foo
{
    std::vector<double> pressure = std::vector<double>(4,0); //vector 4 elements = 0
    ...
};
```

BTW: We can't use braced-initializer as `std::vector<double> pressure{4,0};`, because it would initialize the `vector` containing 2 elements with value `4` and `0`, which is not what you want.