# How can a default constructor and a default argument constructor cause ambiguity in cpp?

Tags: c++

Whats the difference between the default constructor and deafult argument constructor? An example will be helpful

Comment: what is a "default argument constructor" ?

Comment: @idclev I think something like the difference between `void foo();` and `void foo(int bar = 1);`

Comment: well, let's assume class `A` has two constructor `A()` and `A(int a=0)`. when you declare the variable `A a();` in some scope, what does it mean as you think? Is it `A()` or `A(0)` ?

Comment: @JoonaYoon `A a();` declares a function that returns an `A`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 No, it is an instance `a` of type `A`. i told it is declared in *some scope*, not a defining function.

Comment: @JoonaYoon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse It declares a function called `a` that returns an `A`

Comment: @idclev463035818 okay i got it. but it is not the problem about this question what it is function or something. ambiguity rely on calling which constructor.

Comment: @JoonaYoon I know this isnt the problem of the question, thats why I think your comment can be deleted. It is misleading

Comment: @idclev463035818 so could you look at line 9 on [this code](https://ideone.com/KlVyib)? declaration of its is function? not an instance by calling a default constructor? i am so confused...

Comment: @JoonaYoon look at this error message: https://godbolt.org/z/obPq79

Comment: @idclev463035818 OMG. great thanks. i used it sometimes but its first time got error msg. but I can not edit above wrong comment by system. sorry about that. i won't delete a comment for good history to me. thx.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you mean something like this:

```
struct foo {
    foo(int x = 1) {}
    foo() {}
};
```

A [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) is one that can be called without arguments (and I suppose that is what you misunderstood). Both constructors above are default constructors. They both can be called without arguments and when you call the constructor via

```
foo f;
```

Both are viable and there is no way for the compiler to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @YatharthKumar by having only a single default constructor. Having more than one is uncommon

Comment: @YatharthKumar yes, you can keep both, you can call the first when you provide an argument to it, but you cannot call either of them without argument, because they are ambiguous. If you have problem with some code, I can only help you after seeing the code. Maybe you want to open a new question to ask about your actual problem. Please do not change this question to ask for something else, because the current answers answer the question as is

Answer (score 2):

A constructor where all the arguments have defaults *is also* a default constructor for the class.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int = 0){};
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
}
```

will not compile as there are two candidate default constructors so overload resolution will fail. (Note that `Foo f(1);` will compile as overload resolution is no longer ambiguous.)