# C++: Initializing with a temporary object that uses its default constructor declares a function prototype instead of a variable

Tags: c++, constructor

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  // constructor 1
  A() { std::cout << "A() called" << std::endl; }

  // constructor 2
  A(const A&) { std::cout << "A(const A&) called" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  // statement 1
  A x1;

  // statement 2
  A x2( A() );

  return 0;
}
```

I've compiled it with GCC 4.7, 5.1 and 8.1. I got the same results from C++98 to C++17.

Statement 1 creates an `A` variable that calls constructor 1.

Statement 2 declares a prototype of a function that takes a function pointer as its argument and returns a new A object:

```cpp
A ( A (*)() )
```

I was expecting that statement 2 would create an `A` variable that calls constructor 2 since I am initializing with a temporary `A` object.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Can someone help me understand this unexpected situation?

Comment: @Botje, I don't think so. There, they were already expecting that it is a function declaration. In my case, I didn't even know that a function can be declared that way and I was also not trying to declare ```x2``` as a function. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly why I linked it. The problem you are facing is called ["most vexing parse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse) (your code is explicitly listed!) and it is solved by using brace-initialization `A x2{ A() };` or construction by assignment `A x2 = A();`

Comment: @Botje, your examples do declare objects but they don't use constructor 2. To be fair, it's not a straight up "no". They mentioned [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ambig.res) which led me to understanding a little bit more about this "vexing parse".

Comment: Did you read the second link I posted? Your exact problem line is the example they use.

Answer (score -1):

In what is labelled *statement 2* inside your code, you are creating a function pointer pointing to a new object, like you mention, but you don't instruct the program to actually store it, so `x2`, left as is in your snippet code, copies the pointer to a bygone temporary.

Storing the temporary `A` object from the function pointer will compile correctly:

```
// statement 2
A x2( *(new A()) );
```

[Since this is just for the sake of shedding light on this particular issue, we'll overlook that we are more than likely to create a memory leak if the line above finds its way in a real code base, because we have no means of control of the `new A` object that gets copied in `x2`.]

The output will be

```
A() called
A() called
A(const A&) called
```

Basically, yours was a good try, but unfortunately you cannot get away from creating another `A()` object, if you don't want to copy `x2` from `x1`.

In order to save one constructor call, we could construct `x2` from `x1`: using a function pointer, we first define it:

```
// statement 2
A (*fcnptr)(A);
A x2( (*fcnptr)(x1) );
```

which is the same as, more trivially

```
A x2(x1);
```

without using function pointers.
The output:

```
A() called
A(const A&) called
```

Comment: Thank you. I've checked [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ambig.res) and it seems that this is one of C++'s weird side that I may not ever wanna be. What a day.

Comment: Nevermind, I understood you wanted to see the second constructor implemented.