# How to access class member function in a namespace in C++

Tags: c++, object, oop, namespaces

I've got a namespace. The class is in a namespace.

```
namespace SALES
{
    class Sales
    {
    ...
```

I've created functions.

```
void SALES::Sales::set()
{
   ...
```

Now I'm creating an object
`SALES::Sales interactive ();`

but I can't get to methods.
Point my error out, please.

`interactive.set();` // doesn't work

`SALES::interactive.set();` // doesn't work

`interactive.SALES::set();` // doesn't work

Comment: (1) Method 'set' could not be resolved. (2)Request for member 'set' in 'interactive', which is of non-class type 'SALES::Sales()'

Comment: `SALES::Sales interactive ();` is parsed as function declaration. Try `SALES::Sales interactive {};` or simply `SALES::Sales interactive;` It's called [Most vexing parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse).

Comment: Now it's obvious `SALES::Sales interactive;` Nothing to do with namespaces at all. Please in the future be a bit more descriptive than 'doesn't work'.

Comment: @13.tamil Completely irrelevant comment, and generally bad advice too.

Comment: Thanks to all of the comments. It seems, I have found the culprit: my default constructor was not full (all defaults for variables) and the function didn't create an object with `SALES::Sales interactive;` This is why I tried the () version

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks to everyone!!! Now it seems as a wrong question. Should I delete it?

Comment: @MykolaTetiuk If it worked for you, there is a chance that it might help someone else. So consider not deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to access non-static members of a function is by using the [*member of object*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators) operator. For example,

```cpp
class SomeObject {
public:
    SomeObject() {}

    void SayHello() { ... }
    
    int age = 10;
};

// When calling members.
SomeObject object;
object.SayHello();
int age = object.age;
```

And when instantiating, use `SALES::Sales interactive;` or `SALES::Sales interactive{};` instead. If not when you try to do it like this: `SALES::Sales interactive ();`, C++ will try to resolve it as a function. Now in your case, the first; `interactive.set();` needs to work.

If it still doesn't work, it might have to do with the accessibility of members. Classes by default make their members private; only the friend classes and itself can access those objects. So make sure that the members are public.