# Unsure if I'm implementing c++ classes appropriately

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am new to c++ and have some other minor programming experience currently taking a college class intro to c++, we started into ADT's last week and were posed with the problem of converting a TicTacToe game that we worked on previously into a program that utilizes classes to operate. I have organized my code like we were shown in class. I found an example online that was close to what I had available to work with and attempted structuring it like the example. the code currently will compile without error but doesn't draw the board or call the user. Any help would be appreciated again I'm completely new to c++ so I assume there are things not done efferently or that are bad practice I apologize ahead of time.
Thanks

main.cpp

```
    #include "tictactoe.h"
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;


    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        int input;
        do
        {
            tictactoe boardDisplay();
            tictactoe user();
    
        }  while (input != 0);
    
 
        return 0;
    }
```

tictactoe.h

```
    #ifndef TICTACTOE_H
    #define TICTACTOE_H

    class tictactoe
    {
        public:
            tictactoe();
            void boardDisplay();
            void user();                                                
            void alreadyTaken();
            void winState();
            void declareWinner(char);    
        protected:
    };

    #endif
```

and then a separate cpp file for the class

tictactoe.cpp

```
    #include "tictactoe.h"
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    tictactoe::tictactoe()
    {}
       int input;                                                      //user input variable
       int turn = 0;                                                   //gamer turn counter
       char xo = ' ';                                                  // X O board input        
    
       char board[10] = {' ','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};     //board contents 
                                                                    //using 10 elements to match squares
                                                                    //with appropriate array elements.
                                                                  //Note: Using 1 array is easier than 3!

       void tictactoe::boardDisplay(){
           cout << " " << board[1] << " " << "|" << " " << board[2] << " " << "|" << " " << board[3] << " " << endl;               // draws the board
    
           cout << "----------" << endl;
    
           cout << " " << board[4] << " " << "|" << " " << board[5] << " " << "|" << " " << board[6] << " " << endl;               // draws the board
    
           cout << "----------" << endl;
    
           cout << " " << board[7] << " " << "|" << " " << board[8] << " " << "|" << " " << board[9] << " " << endl;               
    
           cout << "Turn#: " << turn << ".  Please choose a number, 1 - 9 (or 0 to quit): ";   // prompts the user for a spot on the board
        
           }

   void tictactoe::user(){
           turn++;
        
           cin >> input;
        
           cout << endl << endl;

           if(turn % 2 == 0)   //checks if turn is odd or even player 1 odd and player 2 even
               xo = 'X';
           else
              xo = 'O';
    
           switch (input)   
           {
               case 1:  
                   if ((board[1] == 'x')||(board[1] == 'X')||(board[1] == 'o')||(board[1] == 'O')) // decides if spot is already taken
                   {
                       alreadyTaken();
                       break;
                   }
                   board[1] = xo;
                   break;
            
                case 2: 
                   if ((board[2] == 'x')||(board[2] == 'X')||(board[2] == 'o')||(board[2] == 'O')) // same process for all cases
                   {
                       alreadyTaken();
                       break;
                   } 
                   board[2] = xo;
                   break;
               case 3:  
                   if ((board[3] == 'x')||(board[3] == 'X')||(board[3] == 'o')||(board[3] == 'O'))
                   {
                       alreadyTaken();
                       break;
                   }
                   board[3] = xo;
                   break; 
               case 4:
                   if ((board[4] == 'x')||(board[4] == 'X')||(board[4] == 'o')||(board[4] == 'O'))
                   {
                       alreadyTaken();
                       break;
                   }
                   board[4] = xo;
                   break;
               case 5:  if ((board[5] == 'x')||(board[5] == 'X')||(board[5] == 'o')||(board[5] =='O'))
                   {
                       alreadyTaken();
                       break;
                   }
                   board[5] = xo;
                   break;
               case 6:  
                   if ((board[6] == 'x')||(board[6] == 'X')||(board[6] == 'o')||(board[6] =='O'))
                   {
                       alreadyTaken();
                       break;
                   }
                   board[6] = xo;
                   break;
               case 7:  
                   if ((board[7] == 'x')||(board[7] == 'X')||(board[7] == 'o')||(board[7] =='O'))
                   {
                       alreadyTaken();
                       break;
                   }
                   board[7] = xo;
                   break;
                case 8: 
                   if ((board[8] == 'x')||(board[8] == 'X')||(board[8] == 'o')||(board[8] =='O'))
                   {
                       alreadyTaken();
                       break;
                   }
                   board[8] = xo;
                   break;
               case 9:  
               if ((board[9] == 'x')||(board[9] == 'X')||(board[9] == 'o')||(board[9] =='O'))
                   {
                       alreadyTaken();
                       break;
                   }
                   board[9] = xo;
                   break;
               case 0:  
                   break;                                                      //quit flag
               default: 
                   cout << "You did not enter a valid input" << endl;
           }
           winState();
   }

    void tictactoe::alreadyTaken(){
        cout << "This spot is already taken, try again." << endl; 
        turn--;
    }

    void tictactoe::winState() {
    
        if((board[1] == board[4]) && (board[4] == board[7]))              //Win on Left Column
            declareWinner(board[7]);
    
        else if((board[2] == board[5]) && (board[5] == board[8]))         //Win on Middle Column
            declareWinner(board[8]);
 
        else if((board[3] == board[6]) && (board[6] == board[9]))         //Win on Right Column
            declareWinner(board[9]);
    
        else if((board[1] == board[2]) && (board[2] == board[3]))         //Win on Top Row
            declareWinner(board[3]);
    
        else if((board[4] == board[5]) && (board[5] == board[6]))         //Win on Middle Row
            declareWinner(board[6]);

        else if((board[7] == board[8]) && (board[8] == board[9]))         //Win on Bottom row
            declareWinner(board[9]);
    
        else if((board[1] == board[5]) && (board[5] == board[9]))       //Win On '\' Diagonal
            declareWinner(board[1]);
    
        else if((board[3] == board[5]) && (board[5] == board[7])){      //Win on '/' Diagonal
            declareWinner(board[7]);
        }

   }

    void tictactoe::declareWinner(char val) {                                     //Displays the Winner
        switch(val) 
        {
            case 'X': cout << "X Wins!";
                break;
            case 'O': cout << "O Wins!";
                break;
        }
        input = 0;                              // end game
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you're not totally clear on the difference between instances and classes. In your `main` method, `tictactoe boardDisplay();` creates an instance of the `tictactoeclass` named `boardDisplay` using the default constructor. It does not call the member function `boardDisplay`. What you may have meant to do is something like `tictactoe game; game.boardDisplay(); game.user();`, which would call those functions using `game` as the specific instance.

Comment: Oh, right, most vexing parse, it's not even creating instances. Neither parse of the line is what you actually want the code to be doing there, however.

Comment: the input variable in your main function is always 0 and never gets changed, the loop only runs once

Comment: A final remark: Your loop is invoking undefined behavior because the condition `do .. while(input != 0)` is reading the value of `input` without ever initializing it. `input` in `main` has nothing to do with `input` the member variable of a `tictactoe` instance.

Comment: @Yamahari is there a way to use the input variable from users by declaring it in a different scope inside the tictactoe.cpp file? Or would I have to make that change in the .h file?

Comment: @NathanPierson — this is not the [most vexing parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). These are simply function declarations,just like `int f();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines

```
tictactoe boardDisplay();
tictactoe user();
```

don't do what you hope to do. They are just function declarations. Look up "The Most Vexing Parse in C++" to understand why.

What you need:

```
tictactoe game;
game.boardDisplay();
game.user();
```

Related links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse
- [What is the purpose of the Most Vexing Parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse)

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that the instance need to be created outside of the loop, but the functions should be called inside it.

Comment: This clears it up I knew it was something small like that but couldn't decide what. Thanks

Comment: This is not the [most vexing parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). It is simply a function declaration, just like `int f();`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, agreed. It is strongly related though.