# Class instance creation difference

Tags: c++

X works but Y does not.
Whats the difference between X and Y?
And passing them as base reference to foo?

```
class Base { };
class Derived : Base{};

void foo(Base& p) {}

int main() {
    Derived x = Derived();
    Derived y();

    foo((Base&)x);
    foo((Base&)y);
}
```

Comment: That's called [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse

Comment: Derived *is not a* Base, because of `private` inheritance.  Change `Derived y();` to `Derived y{};` or just `Derived y;`.

Comment: `Derived y();` is declaring a **function** named `y` that takes no parameters and returns a `Derived`.  It is NOT declaring a **variable** named `y` of type `Derived` that is default-constructed, as you are expecting. Use `Derived y;` or `Derived y{};` for that variable instead.

Comment: Ok thank you I understand now...