# Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code below down?

Tags: c++, class, c++11

```
class G
{
    public:
    G() { puts("G"); }
    G(const G& g) { puts("copy"); }
}
int main()
{
    G A();
    G B(A);
}
```

Compiling the code above with  `g++ -std=c++11` will cause `error: no matching function for call to ‘G::G(G (&)())’`.

But if I replace the code `G A();` with `G A;`,everything is ok.

Can anyone tell me why ? And what's the difference between `G A();` and `G A;`

Comment: `G A();` declares a *function* which takes no argument and returns a `G` object by value. Either drop the parentheses or use curly-braces.

Comment: Just another victim of [the most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse).