# Cpp/C++ Assign Default value to default constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, declaration, default-constructor

This seems like a really easy question but I can't find a working solution(maybe it is the rest of the code too).
So basically how do you assign a value to an object created with the default constructor, when the custom constructor has that variable as a parameter? (hopefully this is understandable)

Maybe clearer:
The code below only works if I write `foo ex2(2)` instead of `foo ex2()` inside the main function. So how do I assign a default value to `x` if the object is created with the default constructor

```
class foo {

public:
    int y;
    int x;
    static int counter;

    foo()
    {
        y = counter;
        counter++;
        x = 1;
    };

    foo(int xi) 
    {
        y = counter;
        counter++;
        x = xi;
    };

};

int foo::counter = 0;

int main()
{

    foo ex1(1);
    foo ex2();

    std::cout << ex1.y << "\t" << ex1.x << "\n";
    std::cout << ex2.y << "\t" << ex2.x << "\n";
    std::cin.get();
};
```

Comment: You already are assigning a value with `x = 1;` - I'm not sure what else you want to do

Comment: You should turn on all your compilers warnings: `warning: empty parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]` -> [What is the purpose of the Most Vexing Parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse)

Comment: @UnholySheep my bad the problem was the wrong object declaration of ex2 so it didn't work. Ty tho :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This record

```
foo ex2();
```

is not an object declaration of the class foo.

It is a function declaration that has the return type `foo` and no parameters.

You need to write

```
foo ex2;
```

or

```
foo ( ex2 );
```

or

foo ex2 {};

or

foo ex2 = {};

Answer (score 0):

As said above. Then to assign a default value:

```
class foo {
public:
    int y;
    int x;
    static int counter;
    foo(int xi = 1) : x(xi)
    {
        y = counter;
        counter++;
    };
};
int foo::counter = 0;

int main()
{
    foo ex1(3);
    foo ex2;

    std::cout << ex1.y << "\t" << ex1.x << "\n";
    std::cout << ex2.y << "\t" << ex2.x << "\n";
};
```

Comment: Actually, you made another, mor important change to the original code than providing a default value for `xi`.

Comment: Hi @churill, do you mean the `foo ex2;` part?

Comment: Excatly :) `foo ex2();` (like in the original) would also fail in your version.