# error: expected ',' or '...' before 'nullptr'

Tags: c++

The below code snippet is generating the `error: expected identifier before 'nullptr'` as well as `error: expected ',' or '...' before 'nullptr'` in line `edge minIncoming(nullptr, NOPATH);`
Any idea what is wrong? All I want to do is use the constructor to initialize minIncoming. I tried searching but couldn't find a answer. I apologize in advance if question is too basic.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#define MAXN 8
#define NOPATH 1000000
#define DEBUG

using namespace std;

struct vertex;

struct edge
{
    vertex* node;
    int weight;

    edge(vertex* n, int w) : node(n), weight(w) {}
};

struct vertex
{
    vector< edge > outgoing;
    edge minIncoming(nullptr, NOPATH);
    bool visited;
#ifdef DEBUG
    int id;
#endif // DEBUG
};
```

Comment: "most vexing parse" fix is `edge minIncoming{ nullptr, NOPATH };` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/zn7qGEKvx

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know what MVP was but now I understand. Could you add this comment as an answer so I could approve it or nah?

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of the Most Vexing Parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse) or [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets/181463#181463)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to C++'s [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), the statement:

```
 edge minIncoming(nullptr, NOPATH);
```

is treated as if you're declaring a function named `minIncoming` with return type of `edge` and taking two parameters. But since during declaration of a function, we specify the types of the parameters instead of specifying the arguments(as you did in your program), the program gives the mentinoed error.

To **solve** this replace that statement with:

```
edge minIncoming{ nullptr, NOPATH };
```

Now the above statement defines an object(data member) named `minIncoming` of type `edge` while passing the two initializers.