# Implicitly calling constructor

Tags: c++, class, implicit-conversion

I have this exam question that says :

> Bar can be properly constructed with ...

and I have to choose the correct option(s):

> ```
> class Bar{
> public:
>     Bar(std::string);
>     Bar(int a=10,double b=7.10, char c='e');
> };
> ```
>
> a) Bar{4,2,6};
>
> b) Bar{"xyz",2};
>
> c) Bar(true,false);
>
> d) Bar{5,"abc"};
>
> e) Bar();

I think that it can certainly be constructed with `a)` (implicit conversion from `int` to `char`). I also think that it should not be possible to construct with `b)` and `d)` because there is no implicit conversion from `const char*` to `double`. I think that `Bar()` is a function prototype, so it's out of the question. Then `c)` true and false can be converted to `int` and `double`. So my thoughts are : `a)` and `d)` can construct `Bar` properly.

Am I right? Can someone with more experience confirm this?

Comment: [Hint] You can try compiling the code to see what the compiler accepts.

Comment: `Bar::Bar(int a=10,double b=7.10, char c='e')` is a default ctor so `Bar()` will work.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/KneWW11x5

Comment: So if it was  Bar b() instead will that be interpreted as a function?

Comment: @Xavi Yes `Bar b();` declares a function due to [vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse).

Comment: thanks a lot all of you!

Comment: `Bar b();` is simply a function declaration, just like `int f();`. This is **not** the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse); it comes from the same rule, and is occasionally confusing, but the most vexing parse it **always** vexing, which is why it's called that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that Bar() is function prototype so it's out of question.

No, `Bar::Bar(int =10,double =7.10, char ='e')` declares a **default constructor**, so `Bar()` is completely valid and will [use the above default ctor](https://godbolt.org/z/jaj1GavfW).

Similarly, `Bar{4,2,6};` and `Bar(true, false)` will also use the default ctor.

```
class Bar{
public:
Bar(std::string){}
Bar(int a=10,double b=7.10, char c='e'){
    std::cout <<"default " << std::endl; 
}
};
int main()
{
    Bar(true, false); //uses default ctor
    Bar();           //uses default ctor see demo link below
    Bar{1,2,3};      //uses default ctor

}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jaj1GavfW)